# voller etwas. Is etwas here Genitiv?

Tags: grammatical-case

> Das ist eine Gesellschaft voller Geheimnisse.

If I were to add an adjective to "Geheimnisse", which case would it take?

> Das ist eine Gesellschaft voller gruseligen Geheimnisse.

Is "gruseligen" correct?

Comment: No. Voller gruseliger.

Comment: Why? Which case is this?

Comment: Your guess in the question headline is right: Genitiv

Comment: Ok. Thank you!!

Comment: @HaraldLichtenstein, please don’t answer in comments. Also, I think that your suggestion is wrong or at least poor style.

Comment: DWDW has an example: *Die Straße war voller halbversteckter heimlichtuender Kellerkneipen* (U. Becher). I'm confused by putting the adjective after the noun though; can you do that in German?

Comment: What I'm getting at is that the two English sentences "This is a glassful of hot water" and "This is a glass full of hot water." have different meanings ("How much hot water? A glassful" vs. "What's in the glass? Hot Water"). But DeepL gives them the same German translation: *Dies ist ein Glas voll heißem Wasser.* Perhaps the German version is ambiguous. I would go with *Das ist eine Gesellschaft, die voller gruseliger Geheimnisse ist* too avoid this.

Comment: @RDBury To quote Durrel: "The genetive with adjectives is mainly restricted to formal German. A number of the adjectives concerned have alternative constructions in less formal registers. *With the exception of **bar**, they follow the noun*. z.B. Sie waren **des langen Streites** müde. (They were tired of the long quarrel).

Answer (score 2):

(Literary examples are from the [DWDS corpus](https://www.dwds.de/r)).

## Regular construction: genitive

In general, noun phrases in the genitive can modify other nouns. As feminine and plural nouns have no distinct genitive suffix, case is shown solely by *-er* on the adjective. The following examples use compound adjectives with *-voll* in order to exclude any special properties of *voll(er)*.

> »Aus dem Kabinett Ihrer Majestät der Kaiserin,« sagte er mit der Miene ehrfurchtsvoll**er** Devotion.
>
> In ihr aber wuchs das Gefühl ahnungsvoll**er** Beklommenheit, das sie gleich beim Betreten des kleinen Gemaches empfunden.
>
> Vielleicht zitterte auf dem Bilde unserer Zärtlichkeit mehr als ein Blick schmerzvoll**er** Entsagung oder wehmütig**er** Eifersucht.

The general rule for adjectives modifying the same noun is that they bear the same ending. Examples with *voller* and a feminine or plural noun similar to the example given in the question:

> wir leben in einer Zeit voll**er** ängstlich**er** Fragen
>
> Ein so junger Mensch zieht sich fünf Jahre in ein Haus voll**er** alt**er** Sirenen zurück!
>
> Ich sah das vieltausendköpfige Publikum, ein unruhiges Meer vol**ler** bösartig**er** Fratzen.

## Irregular construction: preposition

The current revision of the Duden grammar (paragraph 917) as well as the [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/voller) dictionary count *voll(er)* among prepositions with genitive or dative.

The reason becomes clear when looking at examples with masculine and neuter (singular) nouns: With *voller*, the noun has no genitive singular suffix *-s*. Also note that the genitive singular masculine and neuter form of the adjective *voll* would be *vollen*. So the following examples can be considered to show the preposition *voller* combined with a dative (or at least non-genitive) form of the noun:

> Die Wirtin wirft **voller Zorn** die leere Schachtel auf den Tisch.
>
> das Leben ist **voller Risiko**

Two examples with an added adjective showing the strong dative suffix *-em*.

> ein Buch voller schwarz**em** Humor ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/voller))
>
> Ich bin Big Mind, Big Heart: vollständig entspannt, voller Gelassenheit, voller Freude, voller inner**em** Frieden. ([Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=vDpEDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA362&dq=%22voller%20innerem%22&pg=PA362#v=onepage&q=%22voller%20innerem%22&f=false))

Substituting noun phrases in the genitive in the examples above is impossible.

> *Die Wirtin wirft vollen Zorns die leere Schachtel auf den Tisch.
> *das Leben ist vollen Risikos
> *ein Buch vollen schwarzen Humors
> *ich bin vollen inneren Friedens

## Given example

> Das ist eine Gesellschaft voller gruselig**er** Geheimnisse.

With *Geheimnisse* being plural, there is no syntactic impediment to interpreting *voller* as an adjective in the genitive and *-er* is the only option.

This points to a problem with the Duden analysis: If *voller* was a completely regular preposition similar to *trotz* and the like, the following should be okay:

> *Das ist eine Gesellschaft voller gruselig**en** Geheimnisse**n**.

Therefore, *voll(er)* definitely has idiosyncratic properties that are not accounted for by simply listing it among prepositions such as *trotz*.

Finally, it would be remiss not to point out that there are also semantic reasons for distinguishing several kinds of *voll(er)*.

> die volle Wut = die ganze Wut
>
> voller Wut = voll von, erfüllt von Wut

The simplest view would be to say that the first example has the adjective and the second one the preposition.

Comment: Martin Durrell's book "Hammer's German Grammar and Usage" (https://www.academia.edu/27664766/hammer_s_german_grammar_and_usage_5th_ed_indexable_pdf) has a helpful description for English speakers of adjectives that govern various cases, including the uses of "voll" and "voller". See section 6.5.3(b) of Hammer.

Comment: @user02814 Although *voll* is of course historically an adjective, listing *voll(er)* among adjectives is a bit weird: complements of adjectives usually appear on the left of the adjective *seiner Sache sicher, des Problems bewusst* etc., whereas *voll(er)* can only have them on the right. That is probably one of the reasons why Duden counts it as a preposition. In the end, the word has idiosyncratic properties that cannot be explained by assigning it to any part of speech.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated and weird.

First of all: The correct form for "gruselig" in your sentence must be "gruseliger":

> Das ist eine Gesellschaft **voller gruseliger Geheimnisse.**

What I found out about the case, is this:
When the noun is in plural, it seems to be in genitive case. But when you use a noun in singular, it seems to be dative case.
This is very weird, I never before have seen something before.

---

Here are the details:

Let's begin with some examples (including your sentence):

- plural

  > Der Korb war **voller Äpfel.**
  > Das ist eine Gesellschaft **voller gruseliger Geheimnisse.**
- singular

  > Das Volk sang **voller Glauben** in der Messe mit.
  > Seine Geschichten sind **voller schwarzem Humor.**

Now, let's decline these words and phrases:

- **Äpfel**

  1. Nom.: Die **Äpfel** sind rot.  *-- **MATCH***
  2. Gen.: Er beraubte uns der **Äpfel.**  *-- **MATCH***
  3. Dat.: Die Hitze schadet den **Äpfeln.** *-- NO match*
  4. Akk.: Wir sehen die **Äpfel.**  *-- **MATCH***
- **gruselige Geheimnisse**

  - strong declension

    1. Nom.: **Gruselige Geheimnisse** sind unheimlich. *-- NO match*
    2. Gen.: Er brüstete sich **gruseliger Geheimnisse.** *-- **MATCH***
    3. Dat.: **Gruseligen Geheimnissen** mangelt es nicht an Spannung. *-- NO match*
    4. Akk.: Man muss **gruselige Geheimnisse** nicht immer mögen. *-- NO match*
  - weak declension

    1. Nom.: Die **gruseligen Geheimnisse** kennt niemand. *-- NO match*
    2. Gen.: Er gedachte der **gruseligen Geheimnisse.** *-- NO match*
    3. Dat.: Heinrich ist den **gruseligen Geheimnissen** zugetan. *-- NO match*
    4. Akk.: Julia liebt die **gruseligen Geheimnisse.** *-- NO match*
  - mixed declension

    1. Nom.: Seine **gruseligen Geheimnisse** sind langweilig. *-- NO match*
    2. Gen.: Er wurde ihrer **gruseligen Geheimnisse** habhaft. *-- NO match*
    3. Dat.: Willi schenkt meinen **gruseligen Geheimnissen** große Aufmerksamkeit *-- NO match*
    4. Akk.: Hans fürchtet unsere **gruseligen Geheimnisse.** *-- NO match*
- **Glaube**

  1. Nom.: Sein **Glaube** ist stark. *-- NO match*
  2. Gen.: Er brüstete sich seines **Glaubens.** *-- NO match*
  3. Dat.: Sie schenkte seinem **Glauben** keine Beachtung.  *-- **MATCH***
  4. Akk.: Sie fühlte ihren **Glauben** schwinden.  *-- **MATCH***
- **schwarzer Humor**

  - strong declension

    1. Nom.: **Schwarzer Humor** kann verletzend sein. *-- NO match*
    2. Gen.: Sie bedienst sich **schwarzen Humors.** *-- NO match*
    3. Dat.: **Schwarzem Humor** fehlt oft jegliche Sensibilität.  *-- **MATCH***
    4. Akk.: Man muss **schwarzen Humor** nicht immer mögen. *-- NO match*
  - weak declension

    1. Nom.: Der **schwarze Humor** ist weit verbreitet. *-- NO match*
    2. Gen.: Er brüstete sich des **schwarzen Humors.** *-- NO match*
    3. Dat.: Heinrich ist dem **schwarzen Humor** zugetan. *-- NO match*
    4. Akk.: Julia liebt den **schwarzen Humor.** *-- NO match*
  - mixed declension

    1. Nom.: Ein **schwarzer Humor** ist besser als gar kein Humor. *-- NO match*
    2. Gen.: Er bediente sich eines **schwarzen Humors.** *-- NO match*
    3. Dat.: Sie hat noch nie etwas vom einem **schwarzen Humor** gehört. *-- NO match*
    4. Akk.: Ich würde das einen **schwarzen Humor** nennen. *-- NO match*

---

What you can learn for sure from these examples is that  *"voller"* provides an environment where strong declension has to be used for adjectives. But when you want to find out which case to use, it becomes very confusing.

Let's try it again with "Äpfel" but now with an additional adjective, and in strong declension only (weak and mixed will never match):

> Der Korb war **voller roter Äpfel.**

- **rote Äpfel**

  1. Nom.: **Rote Äpfel** schmecken gut.  *-- NO match*
  2. Gen.: Er bemächtigte sich **roter Äpfel.**  *-- **MATCH***
  3. Dat.: Die Hitze schadet **roten Äpfeln.** *-- NO match*
  4. Akk.: Wir sehen **rote Äpfel.**  *-- NO match*

Lets add an adjective to "Glaube" too:

> Das Volk sang **voller innigem Glauben** in der Messe mit.

- **inniger Glaube**

  1. Nom.: **Inniger Glaube** ist selten. *-- NO match*
  2. Gen.: Er brüstete sich **innigen Glaubens.** *-- NO match*
  3. Dat.: Sie schenkte **innigem Glauben** keine Beachtung.  *-- **MATCH***
  4. Akk.: Sie fühlte **innigen Glauben** aufkeimen.   *-- NO match*

---

So, when the noun is in plural, it seems to be in genitive case. But when you use a noun in singular, it seems to be dative case. This is very weird!

I didn't not find any resources on internet, that brings more light to this strange behaviour of *"voller".*

Comment: If an adjective enters, I would replace “voller” with “voll”. Is that just me?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: »voller schwarzem Humor« (Singular!) steht sogar im Duden als Beispiel für die korrekte Verwendung von »voller«: [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/voller) Siehe auch [Zwei schwungvolle Geschichten voller schwarzem Humor](https://www.amazon.de/Tod-Hase-die-Unsinkbare-ich-ebook/dp/B00J4TL4V2/ref=sr_1_6?dchild=1&keywords=Schwarzer+Humor&qid=1607290889&refinements=p_n_binding_browse-bin%3A600849031&s=books&sr=1-6) oder [Ein Buch voller schwarzem Humor](https://buchlabor.home.blog/2019/08/25/ein-buch-voller-schwarzem-humor/)

Comment: Auch Singular: [ein sehr kleiner Ort **voller großer Liebe**](https://www.tripadvisor.at/Restaurant_Review-g187855-d3544500-Reviews-Confectionery_Bella_sicilia-Turin_Province_of_Turin_Piedmont.html) oder [Und trotzdem ist Tenzin noch so **voller gutem Glauben.**](https://www.lovelybooks.de/autor/Tenzin-Lahkpa/Auf-der-Suche-nach-Erleuchtung-fand-ich-das-Licht-2034638119-w/leserunde/2230320444/2236208441/) oder [»Hinterwald« steckt **voller packender Spannung**](https://lass-den-wookie-gewinnen.de/tag/hinterwald/)

Comment: @Carsten S: I would use both "voll" and "voller" with and without adjective. These are two different words for me.